# How to deserialize nested JSON object that have the same name as my Java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying map this JSON

```
{
"coord": {
    "lon": 26.94,
    "lat": 43.27
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 802,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "scattered clouds",
        "icon": "03d"
    }
],
"base": "model",
"main": {
    "temp": 19.3,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 66,
    "temp_min": 19.3,
    "temp_max": 19.3,
    "sea_level": 1012,
    "grnd_level": 971
},
"wind": {
    "speed": 6.91,
    "deg": 182
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 38
},
"dt": 1573204594,
"sys": {
    "country": "BG",
    "sunrise": 1573188939,
    "sunset": 1573224978
},
"timezone": 7200,
"id": 727233,
"name": "Shumen",
"cod": 200
}
```

To my own created java object

```java
    package com.kosev.willitrain.model;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Weather {
        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String cityName;
        private String type; // for weather type eg: Cloudy, Sunny, Raining etc...
        private float temp;
        private float tempMin;
        private float tempMax;
        private float windSpeed;
        private String icon;
        private float lon;
        private float lat;

        public Weather(){}

        @JsonProperty("main")
        private void unpackMain(Map<String,String> main) {
            temp = Float.parseFloat(main.get("temp"));
            tempMin = Float.parseFloat(main.get("temp_min"));
            tempMax = Float.parseFloat(main.get("temp_max"));
        }

        @JsonProperty("coord")
        private void unpackCoord(Map<String,String> coord) {
            lon = Float.parseFloat(coord.get("lon"));
            lat = Float.parseFloat(coord.get("lat"));
        }

        @JsonProperty("weather")
        private void unpackWeather(Map<String,String> weather) {
            type = weather.get("main");
            icon = weather.get("icon");
        }
    }
```

The error i get is this:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 46] (through reference chain: com.kosev.willitrain.model.Weather["weather"])

Comment: Where exactly are the words "Cloudy", "Sunny" etc in JSON?

Comment: Weather is an array of dictionaries; you can map an array to a `java.util.List` but not to a `java.util.Map` like you're doing. Maybe you want to map it to a `List<Map<String,String>>`?

Comment: But it's unclear why, when you already have Jackson, which can map Json to Java objects, why you would still do it yourself in methods that take Maps.

Comment: I think better solution is create DTO wich is one to one as JSON (without fileds wich you don't need) and create factory to create your DTO based on the first one.
Is more readable and you don't think about mapping - cares about it jackson mapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    package com.sample.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class DemoApplicationTests {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String response = "{\n" + "\"coord\": {\n" + "    \"lon\": 26.94,\n" + "    \"lat\": 43.27\n" + "},\n"
                + "\"weather\": [\n" + "    {\n" + "        \"id\": 802,\n" + "        \"main\": \"Clouds\",\n"
                + "        \"description\": \"scattered clouds\",\n" + "        \"icon\": \"03d\"\n" + "    }\n"
                + "],\n" + "\"base\": \"model\",\n" + "\"main\": {\n" + "    \"temp\": 19.3,\n"
                + "    \"pressure\": 1012,\n" + "    \"humidity\": 66,\n" + "    \"temp_min\": 19.3,\n"
                + "    \"temp_max\": 19.3,\n" + "    \"sea_level\": 1012,\n" + "    \"grnd_level\": 971\n" + "},\n"
                + "\"wind\": {\n" + "    \"speed\": 6.91,\n" + "    \"deg\": 182\n" + "},\n" + "\"clouds\": {\n"
                + "    \"all\": 38\n" + "},\n" + "\"dt\": 1573204594,\n" + "\"sys\": {\n" + "    \"country\": \"BG\",\n"
                + "    \"sunrise\": 1573188939,\n" + "    \"sunset\": 1573224978\n" + "},\n" + "\"timezone\": 7200,\n"
                + "\"id\": 727233,\n" + "\"name\": \"Shumen\",\n" + "\"cod\": 200\n" + "}";
        Weather weather = objectMapper.readValue(response, Weather.class);
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Weather {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String cityName;
    private String type; // for weather type eg: Cloudy, Sunny, Raining etc...
    private float temp;
    private float tempMin;
    private float tempMax;
    private float windSpeed;
    private String icon;
    private float lon;
    private float lat;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("base")
    public Weather() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("main")
    private void unpackMain(Map<String, String> main) {
        temp = Float.parseFloat(main.get("temp"));
        tempMin = Float.parseFloat(main.get("temp_min"));
        tempMax = Float.parseFloat(main.get("temp_max"));
    }

    @JsonProperty("coord")
    private void unpackCoord(Map<String, String> coord) {
        lon = Float.parseFloat(coord.get("lon"));
        lat = Float.parseFloat(coord.get("lat"));
    }

    @JsonProperty("weather")
    private void unpackWeather(List<Map<String, String>> weather) {
        System.out.println(weather);
        type = weather.get(0).get("main"); // Taken first element , change as per your requirement
        icon = weather.get(0).get("icon");
    }
}
```

Weather should be list of map , instead of Map.

Comment: This works! I did not pay attention to the ObjectMapper and was trying this solution with GSON, does not work. Wanted to share in case it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

This is your structure:

```
public class JsonClass {
    Coord coord;
    List<Weather> weather;
    String base;
    Main main;
    Wind wind;
    Clouds clouds;
    long dt;
    Sys sys;
    int timezone;
    int id;
    String name;
    int cod;

    private class Coord {
        private float lon;
        private float lat;
    }

    private class Weather {
        int id;
        String main;
        String description;
        String icon;
    }

    private class Main {
        float temp;
        int pressure;
        ...
    }

    private class Wind {
        float speed;
        int deg;
    }

    private class Clouds {
        int all;
    }

    private class Sys {
        String country;
        long sunrise;
        long sunset;
    }
  }
```

To read rhis json just call `readValue`:

```
ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
JsonClass jsnClz = MAPPER .readValue(json, JsonClass.class);
```

Dont forget to add `getter`/`setter` or use lombok annotations.